# Connecting to server with id and password

Tags: json, elasticsearch

Im all new to json, and i have tried to research what might be the problem but without luck.

I am using Kibana (dev tools) and i have to connect to the Danish Company Register so i an pull data.

They have provided this line of code to connect:

```
curl -u "ID:Password" -XGET http://distribution.virk.dk/cvr-permanent/_mapping
```

But i get this result

```
 {
"error" : {
"root_cause" : [
  {
    "type" : "index_not_found_exception",
    "reason" : "no such index",
    "resource.type" : "index_or_alias",
    "resource.id" : "cvr-permanent",
    "index_uuid" : "_na_",
    "index" : "cvr-permanent"
  }
],
"type" : "index_not_found_exception",
"reason" : "no such index",
"resource.type" : "index_or_alias",
"resource.id" : "cvr-permanent",
"index_uuid" : "_na_",
"index" : "cvr-permanent"
  },
    "status" : 404
}
```

In their startup "how to" document they also suggested this (followed up by other commands):

```
curl -XPOST -u “ID:Password” http://distribution.virk.dk/cvr-permanent/virksomhed/_search -d '
{
"_source":["Vrvirksomhed.virksomhedMetadata.nyesteNavn.navn"],
"query":{"term":{"Vrvirksomhed.cvrNummer":"12345678"}}
}
```

But i get the same result.

Can anyone se what i am missing? 
Thanks!

Comment: It simply means that the index name `cvr-permanent` does not exist.

Comment: @Val A silly question, but im not wrong in the understanding that the index is supposed to exist in advance when this link is provided? Like the function is supposed to connect to something that is already created by them and then i am supposed to search data within it?

Comment: I have truly no idea how that cluster works and what the contract/interface between them and you is.

Answer (score 2):

You might already have figured it out, but here is what works for me when trying to access CVR. Their documentation is kinda of chaotic and not at all up-to-date. I was successful in running the following command:

```
curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u "username:password" -d'
{ "_source": ["Vrvirksomhed.virksomhedMetadata.nyesteNavn.navn"],
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "Vrvirksomhed.cvrNummer": 12345678
    }
  }
}' http://distribution.virk.dk/cvr-permanent/_search
```

It seems like you have a "virksomhed" to much in your endpoint url.

Kind regards,
Michael

Comment: Thanks - using the correct url solved my problem.